# validation rule without entering duplicates numbers

Tags: validation

i have two fields.one is display order type(number), sectionname type(picklist).

now i want  validation rule for each section under picklist displaying the numbers in display order field  without entering duplicates numbers.

Comment: can u share what you have tried so far..

Comment: above i mentioned fields, under section name i have sections like marketing factory,innovation like that. so now each section i want numbering for 1,2,3 like that means marketing factory has 1,2,3 and innovation has 1,2,3, ....

Comment: so now i won't allow for duplicates under each section.

Comment: i want like this only for marketing factory has 1,2,3 and innovation has 1,2,3. but both are in picklist and finally won't allow duplicates like  marketing has 1,1,2,2 and innovation 1,1,2,2, etc

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to achieve this. Create a new custom field of text type and make it unique. Now create a workflow rule to update this field with the concatenation of (Sectionname + Type). You can do the same thing by using formula field instead of text and in formula concatenate (Sectionname + Type).

So whenever a person will try to insert duplicate "Number" record with same picklist value then the error will be thrown. Also you can still use the same "Number" with different picklist values.

Hope this helps you!

Thanks!

Comment: actually what i need means under picklist i have sections, in that under every section means for first section i want 1,2,3, and second section 1,2,3 like that..

Comment: and then for first section i won't allow for duplicates

Comment: second section i won't allow for duplicates like that .....

Comment: overall its allow duplicates but with in the section not allow duplicates

Comment: thanks for giving above solution but it is not hepled for my case